# Kubernetes namespace vanished after cluster reboot

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, namespaces, reboot, rancher

We have a 6 node K8s kubernetes cluster with Rancher running on AWS . The cluster was shutdown and brought up, cluster came back up fine but it has gone back to old state and the few new namespaces are missing , is there a way to recover the namespaces and the pods related to them.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you have used [Kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops) for Kubernetes cluster implementation on AWS, then it might be possible to restore last state of your cluster from S3 bucket, where `Kops` stores its state as well, by specifying `export KOPS_STATE_STORE=s3://yourstatestore` environment variable, look at this [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/state.md) to get more information.

However, keep in mind that `Kops` can revert back only general configuration of your Kubernetes cluster, thus the internal resources (`Deployments`, `Pods`, `Namespaces`, etc.) are not included to this restore list.

Therefore you can consider to use `etcd` [datastore](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-upgrade-etcd/) backup. For example, using `etcdctl` command line [tool](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/tree/master/etcdctl) and regularly create snapshots of `etcd` data store.

Also, you can think about using [heptio/ark](https://github.com/heptio/ark) utility for managing disaster recovery events, specifically for Kubernetes cluster resources and persistent volumes.